# htaccess "if file exists" and "mod_rewrite -f" not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, processwire

I have some problems with a Cache Plugin for ProcessWire but maybe this is a more global question about apache .htaccess restrictions.

**Example:**

I call my page like this: http://example.com/foo
The .htaccess should look up if there is a file `DOCUMENT_ROOT/cache/foo/index.html`
If the file exists, then show the file, or - simplified for this example - just call a success page

Example File structure:

```
cache/foo/index.html (some dummy content)
bar (some dummy content)
file-found.php (the success page with some print_r($_SERVER) stuff)
.htaccess with this content:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1/index.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*) file-found.php
</IfModule>
```

This works properly on my local machine ([SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.4.18 (Unix))
But not with the hosting package where I want to use. ([SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.31 (Unix)) The reaction of the server is just a 404: "The requested URL /foo was not found on this server."

Is it not working because of the version of apache or is it restricted by the hoster?

Btw. the ModRewrite basically works with this hosting. For example like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*) file-found.php
</IfModule>
```

if i call http://example.com/bar, file-found.php is shown

Any ideas how to alternatively solve this "if file exists => then" rule in the htaccess?

Thanks for help!

---

EDIT: even more simplified:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/bar -f
  RewriteRule ^(.*) file-found.php
</IfModule>
```

works local, but not on hoster

Comment: What is value of `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` on live server? Does `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1/index.html` actually exist?

Answer (score 0):

I think that in `RewriteCond` the special characters should be escaped with `\` (if that whole phrase is not in double quotes)

in `RewriteRule` did you try to add flags, like `[L]` or etc..

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but it still does not work, sorry. I tried with escaping the dot too, but nothing changed. Works locally, but not on hoster.

Comment: did you try to add flags to rewriteRule?

Comment: Yes, changes nothing, I'm sorry. For me it feels like the `RewriteCond` is the problem, because in the working example the `RewriteRule` is not making any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you may need `RewriteBase /`):

```
RewriteCond cache%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+(?:/[^/]+)*$ cache/$0/index.html [L]
RewriteCond cache%{REQUEST_URI}index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]+/)*$ cache/$0index.html [L]
```